# GridView with fixed size children

Tags: flutter, dart

I need a grid that contains children of fixed sizes.

GridView expands its children, which is not what I need. The grid should simply size itself according to it's children by setting the crossAxisCount.

My current solution is to use simple columns and rows, but that's so much boilerplate code for just a common widget.

Comment: can you show us the code you made on the grid?

Comment: You like to set fixed size for all grid item or every child will depend on its size?

Comment: Try Wrap Widget

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it dynamically, and supply the value of the `crossAxisCount` dynamically